# Installing Jupyter Notebook using pip in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to install `jupyter notebook` but for some reasons I am not able to install it. I have looked into several links like [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-jupyter-notebook-to-run-ipython-on-ubuntu-16-04) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/847263/install-jupyter-for-python-2-7-in-ubuntu-14-04) but it did not help me. I am guessing the problem here is with the installation of `pip`. When I check the version of `pip` I get the following result :

```
 shaloin@shaolin-Inspiron-3543:~$ pip --version
 pip 1.5.4 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
```

But when I try to upgrade the version of `pip`, I am getting this error :

```
shaloin@shaolin-Inspiron-3543:~$ sudo pip install --upgrade pip
Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pip in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Downloading/unpacking pip
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for pip in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Storing debug log for failure in /home/shaloin/.pip/pip.log
```

So, I searched for the error and I got to know that if you are behind proxy you should try out the following command :

```
sudo pip --proxy [NITS:abcde@]172.16.30.20:8080 install jupyter
```

where `NITS` is the usename `abcde` is the password , `proxy server = 172.16.30.20` and `password=8080`, after which I got the following error :

```
Downloading/unpacking jupyter
Cleaning up...
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 278, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1178, in prepare_files
    url = finder.find_requirement(req_to_install, upgrade=self.upgrade)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 194, in find_requirement
    page = self._get_page(main_index_url, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 568, in _get_page
    session=self.session,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 670, in get_page
    resp = session.get(url, headers={"Accept": "text/html"})
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 467, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 237, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 455, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 558, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/adapters.py", line 305, in send
    conn = self.get_connection(request.url, proxies)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/adapters.py", line 206, in get_connection
    except_on_missing_scheme(proxy)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/utils.py", line 636, in except_on_missing_scheme
    raise MissingSchema('Proxy URLs must have explicit schemes.')
MissingSchema: Proxy URLs must have explicit schemes.

Storing debug log for failure in /home/shaloin/.pip/pip.log
```

I also tried setting up my proxy in this way :

```
set http_proxy=http://username:password@proxyAddress:port

set https_proxy=https://username:password@proxyAddress:port
```

but none of that works for installing `jupyter notebook` using `pip`.

Please don't mark this question as duplicate as because I have been searching for the solution for a long time and none of them works.

Can anyone please help??

Comment: Your `pip` is too old to upgrade itself. Try `get-pip.py`.

Comment: https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py

Comment: I am new to this and I don't have much expertise, so should I run this command `sudo pip get-pip.py`

Comment: No. You need to download that file, then change directories to where that file is located, then run `sudo python get-pip.py`.

Comment: Use a Python virtual environment. Installing/upgrading packages into system Python using ``pip`` is a bad idea because you are potentially trashing the operating system versions of the packages.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton That's good advice, but his version of `pip` is too old to install packages.

Comment: @xaav, where will I get to download the file

Comment: I posted the link.

Comment: Tried that but an error is being displayed : 
`VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f9df35955d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 113] No route to host',)': /simple/pip/`

Comment: Also this message is being shown : `Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`

Comment: @xaav Install ``virtualenv`` from a system package. Use that to create the virtual environment. The ``pip`` installed by ``virtualenv`` may well be newer.

Comment: Then it's `sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv`.

Comment: Also, there seems to be a system connection or configuration issue here. I don't think it's possible to fix in the stackoverflow comments.

Comment: I had installed `jupyter notebook` earlier but due to some reasons I had to format my hard disk. Now, I am trying to install it using the same procedure but it doesn't work

Comment: Can you open https://pypi.python.org/simple/?

Comment: Yes it is showing a list of some packages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For Ubuntu 14.04**

I solved the problem of installation using `anaconda`. The description is given in [this](http://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html) link.I couldn't fix the problem of upgrading `pip`. The steps for installing `jupyter notebook` is given below :

**Step 1** (refer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/505919/how-to-install-anaconda-on-ubuntu))

First we install `anaconda` using `wget`

- 32 bits version

> wget
>   https://3230d63b5fc54e62148e-c95ac804525aac4b6dba79b00b39d1d3.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/Anaconda-2.3.0-Linux-x86.sh

- 64 bits version

> wget
>   https://3230d63b5fc54e62148e-c95ac804525aac4b6dba79b00b39d1d3.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/Anaconda-2.3.0-Linux-x86_64.sh

**Step 2**

After the download is over :

- 32 bits version

  bash Anaconda-2.3.0-Linux-x86.sh
- 64 bits version

  bash Anaconda-2.3.0-Linux-x86_64.sh

After downloading `anaconda`, open your `terminal` and type the following command :

```
$ sudo gedit ~/.profile
```

Add the given line at th end of the file :

```
export PATH=~/anaconda2/bin:$PATH
```

**Step 3**

After adding the line save the file. Open a new `terminal` and go to the directory where `anaconda` was downloaded.

```
$ cd anaconda2/bin
~/anaconda2/bin$ source activate
(root):~/anaconda2/bin$ jupyter notebook
```

The `jupyter notebook` will be opened in the browser.

For more information on `jupyter notebook` you can refer to this [link](http://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html).